# Json.net deserialization of data type ConcurrentBag

Tags: json.net

I have an object with a property of type `ConcurrentBag<object>`.

When I am trying to deserialize a json string to my object using  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), I get an exception which indicates the serializer is failing to convert from an array to the object's `ConcurrentBag<object>` data type.

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write a converter of sorts. Kinda like this post:
[json.net: specify converter for dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845364/json-net-specify-converter-for-dictionary-keys)

This website also has some more examples:
http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/08/26/customizing-the-converter-for-json-net.aspx