# JsonConvert dictionary with key of type Vector2Int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net

I am developing a game which has a class called `UserInfo`.

Inside the `UserInfo` class there is a `public List<Lineup> lineups` variable.

And `Lineup` contains `public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> cardLocations`.

My problem is, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` does correctly produce the result I want, but when I do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>`, `Vector2Int` remains to be a string like `"(x, y)"`.

How should I fix it?

I wrote a `JsonConverter` to convert it, and used

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo, Formatting.Indented, new Vec2Converter())
```

for serialization  and

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(json, new Vec2Converter())
```

to deserialization, but it doesn't work.

Here is my `JsonConverter` script:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Vec2Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var vector2Int = serializer.Deserialize<Vector2Int>(reader);
        Debug.Log(vector2Int);
        return vector2Int;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Vector2Int);
    }
}
```

Another weird thing is that, when I tried to change `Vector2Int` to other data structure like `Lineup` or `Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>`, Unity exited when I clicked play. After I changed it back, it became ok. The ok means it's not exiting but still giving me the error message.

Forgot to put the error message: `ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to UnityEngine.Vector2Int`

Here are the classes.

```
public class UserInfo {
    public string username;
    public int playerID;
    public List<Collection> collection = new List<Collection>();
    public List<Lineup> lineups = new List<Lineup>(); // Here is the problem
    public Dictionary<string, int> contracts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public int coins = 0;
    public int rank = 0;
    public int lastLineupSelected = -1;
    public int winsToday = 0;
    public Stats total = new Stats();
    public Dictionary<string, Stats> boardResults = new Dictionary<string, Stats>();
    public List<Mission> missions;
    public string preferredBoard = "Standard Board";
    public string lastModeSelected = "";
    public int gameID;
    public bool missionSwitched = false;
}

public class Lineup
{
    public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> cardLocations;  // Here is the problem
    public List<Tactic> tactics;
    public string boardName;
    public string lineupName;
    public string general;
    public bool complete;
}

public class Collection
{
    public string name = "";
    public string type = "";
    public int count = 1;
    public int health = 0;
    public int oreCost = 0;
}
```

Comment: Then manually parse the string and create the desired type.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you be more specific? How can I create the desired type?

Comment: Seems dictionary keys are handled specially and need to convertible to strings.  See [Not able To Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504245) and [How can I serialize/deserialize a dictionary with custom keys using Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24681873) and [json.net: specify converter for dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845364).

Comment: @dbc My case is a little bit different. They are just converting dictionary but I am doing a data structure that has a data structure containing a dictionary. And Vector2Int is a unity builtin data type which I can't modify.

Comment: You have to post the class(UserInfo) you are trying to serialize. You haven't done so. You also have to show how you initialized the variable.

Comment: @Programmer posted.

Comment: You said Vector2Int is not serializing/de-serializing but I don't even see Vector2Int there.

Comment: @Programmer Sorry I was trying a new solution so I put Location there by mistake instead of Vector2Int. I have fixed it. Please check it out. Sorry for the trouble. Serializing is fine. I just have trouble deserializing it.

Comment: Where is `Collection` from? Which namespace or is a class you made? If you made it then post the code since it's related to the issue too.

Comment: @Programmer Sorry for the confusion. I made Collection and it is posted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom serializer that derives from `JsonConverter` needs more work and there are few errors. First, note that you are trying to serialize/de-serialize `Dictionary` of `Vector2Int` not just a `Vector2Int` variable.

It's this:

```
public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> cardLocations.
```

not

```
public Vector2Int cardLocations;
```

---

Because of the above statement, your  `override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)` function should be checking for `typeof(Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)` **not** `typeof(Vector2Int)`. Also, you also need to add checks to determine when to run the custom de-serializer.

**Serializing**:

**1**.In the `WriteJson` function that serializes the json, you only need to customize the `Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>` part which is throwing the exception so make sure that the custom code runs **only** when the type is `Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>`. You can do this by putting the code inside `if (value is Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)`.

**2**.Obtain the Dictionary to serialize from the second argument. Call `writer.WriteStartArray()` so that you'll write every value as an array. Now, loop over the `Dictionary`, write the key with `writer.WriteValue(key)` then write the value with `serializer.Serialize(writer, entry.Value);`.

**3**. After/outside the loop call `writer.WriteStartArray();` then return from that function.

If the `if (value is Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)` from **#1** is `false` then simply call `writer.WriteStartObject()` followed by `writer.WriteEndObject()`.

---

**De-Serializing**:

**4**.Determine when to run the custom de-serializer

We used `if (value is Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)` in **#1** when serializing to determine if the custom serializer code should run but for de-serializing, we use `if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)` to determine if we have reached the array part where we did our custom serialization in the `ReadJson` function.

**5**.Use `JArray.Load(reader);` to obtain the array data we serialized. In the returned array, the first element in it is the key in the `Dictionary`.The second element is the value in the `Dictionary`. The third element is the second key in the `Dictionary`. The fourth element is the second value in the `Dictionary` ans so on.

**6**.Separate the keys and values in the `JArray`.

To simplify this, loop over the `JArray` **increment by `2`** instead of `1`. By incrementing by `2`, the key can be easily be retrieved with `JArray[loop + 0]` and the value can be retrieved in the-same loop with `JArray[loop + 1]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.Count; i += 2)
{
    //Key
    string key = jArray[i + 0].ToString();
    //Value
    string value = jArray[i + 1].ToString();
}
```

**7**.Get the key in `Vector2Int` format.

Simply de-serialize the key from **#6** into `Vector2Int` with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vector2Int>(key)`.

**8**.Get the value in `Collection` format.

Simply de-serialize the value from **#6** into `Collection` with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection>(value)`.

**9**.Reconstruct the data

Create new instance of `Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>` then add both the key from **#7** and value from **#8** to it and then return it from the `ReadJson` function.

If the `if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)` from **#4** is `false`, simply create and return new instance of `Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>`    from the `ReadJson` function without adding key or value to it.

```
class Vec2DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    //Deserialize json to an Object
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //Debug.Log("De-serializing!");
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            // Load JArray from stream
            JArray jArray = JArray.Load(reader);

            //Where to re-create the json data into 
            Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> dict = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>();

            if (jArray == null || jArray.Count < 2)
            {
                return dict;
            }

            //Do the loop faster with +=2
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.Count; i += 2)
            {
                //first item = key
                string firstData = jArray[i + 0].ToString();
                //second item = value
                string secondData = jArray[i + 1].ToString();

                //Create Vector2Int key data 
                Vector2Int vect = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vector2Int>(firstData);

                //Create Collection value data
                Collection values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection>(secondData);

                //Add both Key and Value to the Dictionary if key doesnt exit yet
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(vect))
                    dict.Add(vect, values);
            }
            //Return the Dictionary result
            return dict;
        }
        return new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>();
    }

    //SerializeObject to Json
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Serializing!");
        if (value is Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)
        {
            //Get the Data to serialize
            Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> dict = (Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>)value;

            //Loop over the Dictionary array and write each one
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Vector2Int, Collection> entry in dict)
            {
                //Write Key (Vector) 
                serializer.Serialize(writer, entry.Key);
                //Write Value (Collection)
                serializer.Serialize(writer, entry.Value);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            return;
        }
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

Serialize

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo, new Vec2DictionaryConverter());
```

De-serialize

```
UserInfo obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(json, new Vec2DictionaryConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually parse the string and create the desired type.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    var vector2IntString = reader.Value.ToString();//expecting "(x, y)"
    Debug.Log(vector2IntString);
    var parts = vector2IntString.Split(new char[]{ '(', ')', ',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var x = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    var y = int.Parse(parts[1]); 
    var vector2Int = new Vector2Int(x, y);
    return vector2Int;
}
```

The above takes the `"(x, y)"` string and extracts the x and y values. It converts them to integers and uses them to initialize an instance of the desired type (`Vector2Int`)

Some further reading about this particular scenario revealed

> If you only need a type conversion for JSON, you can also use JSON.NET's own custom type converters. Although this doesn't work in the case of dictionary keys.
>
> Lastly, if you have a complex type as your dictionary key, you may want to consider just serializing it as a collection and then deserializing it using a JSON.NET custom converter.

Comment: Thank you but I just tried your code, it's still not working. I think my problem isn't not creating a correct Vector2Int. I guess I should use a converter like lineupConverter or dictConverter? But that's too complicated since I have a lot of variables.

Comment: @Seaky explain what you mean by `not working`. what is  happening?

Comment: I got ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to UnityEngine.Vector2Int before and after trying your code.

Comment: @Seaky On which line?

Comment: It doesn't tell me. I think the script and the code are correct but could it be that the Vector2Int is so inside the data structure that it is not detected?

Comment: Yeah my problem is exactly how to deserialize it. I wrote my solution but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For somebody like me that will run into the same issue.

@Programmer's answer is correct, but may be outdated (I don't know how Json.NET looked like in 2018) and it's too much code (at least for me).

Here's my solution:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

...

[JsonConverter(typeof(Vec2DictionaryConverter))]
public Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> cardLocations;

...

public class DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>> {

    private static readonly string[] SEPARATORS = new[] { "(", ", ", ")" };

    public override Dictionary<Vector2Int, Value> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (JsonToken.Null == reader.TokenType) {
            return null;
        }
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>();
        foreach (var pair in JObject.Load(reader)) {
            var vector = pair.Key.Split(SEPARATORS, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(it => Convert.ToInt32(it));
            var key = new Vector2Int(vector.First(), vector.Last());
            var value = pair.Value.ToObject<Collection>(serializer);
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
            Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection> value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

1. `JsonConverter` Attribute is used instead of passing Converter to `SerializeObject/DeserializeObject` all the time
2. Generic `JsonConverter<Dictionary<Vector2Int, Collection>>` is used, so no need to implement `CanConvert` anymore
3. Only `ReadJson` is implemented as OP didn't have problems with Serialization

This works fine and dandy, although we rely on `Vector2Int.ToString` implementation, but as I found out Unity's `JsonUtility` serialization is faster at least in my tests.